# How to check an IP address is blocked by IP Route?

Tags: route

My server is constantly getting attacked by Amazon India servers.

I added `35.154.0.0/16` range to the route for IP address `35.154.252.15`

`ip route add blackhole 35.154.0.0/16`

But when I check if the IP address is blocked, it does not output anything.

`ip route show 35.154.252.15`

How can I make sure `35.154.252.15` is blocked by `ip route`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man ip-route:

```
   ip route get
          get a single route
          this command gets a single route to a destination and prints its
          contents exactly as the kernel sees it.
```

So try:

```
ip route get 35.154.252.15
```